# Code completion @property PhpStorm

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpstorm

My system is using CodeIgniter 3.x with PhpStorm, I had no Code completion so I used this:

[https://github.com/nicolas-goudry/CI-PHPStorm-Code-Completion](http://github.com/nicolas-goudry/CI-PHPStorm-Code-Completion)

This works like a charm. I have added the file in the project root.

But now I'm using the hmvc model. And it is not working anymore. When I'm in the CodeIgniter "normal" Model, View, Controller classes it works. But when I'm in my module folder it doesn't work. Does Somebody knows an solution?

Edit

I'm a bit closer, the classes where the autocomplete doesn't work extends the MX_Controller. When I change this to CI_Controller it works. So how can I make it work with MX_Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just guessing but maybe adding

```
class MX_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
    } 
}
```

or whatever the class is really called, and then your models etc above it, like the example file. (looks at the github page) Arggh yeah it was nice of him to credit me but I don't know why he never listened to the simplest way to do this - **just name the file autocomplete.php and put it in the application/config folder**. Done! Thats it! Finito. And you do not have to mark any files as plain text with that method. So actually try that first before adding anything to the file. And post back if you can so we can share with others trying the same thing.

Comment: Okay, I have changed the name to autocomplete.php and moved it to the application/config folder. But I have the same result. In codeigniter's own mvc it works. But in the module folder with the other mvc's it doen't. All the classes in the module folder extends the MX_Controller.

Comment: Did you try adding MX controller to the file similar to the other examples?